# DslContext Jooq update timestamp with time zone column as null

Tags: java, jooq, ratpack

I have `Customer` table in postgres DB with `id` as primary key and below columns

```
id -> Integer(PK)
name -> Varchar2
details-> jsonb
created_timestamp -> TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
```

I'm trying to update table based on primary key using [dslContext.resultQuery](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#resultQuery(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) method, i have to update the `name`, `details` the jsonb column and set `created_timestamp` as null

```
String sql = "UPDATE customer SET name = :name, details = :details, created_timestamp = 'NULL' where id = :id RETURNING id";
```

**Java Code**

```
List<Map<String,Object>> updatedCapacityResult = dslContext.resultQuery(sql,
      DSL.param("name","value"),
      DSL.param("details",objectmapper.writeValueAsString(object))).fetchMaps();
```

I'm having error while executing the code and it simply says

```
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [UPDATE customer SET name = :name, details = :details, created_timestamp = 'NULL' where id = :id RETURNING id; ERROR: syntax error at or near "details"
 Position: 60
```

When i removed the code to update `details`, then it started erroring out on `created_timestamp` field, if i just updated the `name` using above query it updates and return the data as well.

Curious what i have missed here and how to updated `jsonb` and `timestamp` columns ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out the issue with `jooq` library, but on updating values to `NULL` i found alternative like using `StringBuilder` and forming it as string

```
String sql = new StringBuilder("UPDATE customer SET" )
                .append("name = '"+name+"', ")
                .append("details = '"+details+"', ")
                .append("created_timestamp = NULL ")
                .append("where id = '"+id+"' RETURNING id").toString();
```

and the just using `resultQuery`

```
 List<Map<String,Object>> updatedCapacityResult = dslContext.resultQuery(sql).fetchMaps();
```

Answer (score 1):

#### The JSONB column

While sometimes, the pgjdbc driver and PostgreSQL server can coerce a string value into a `JSONB` value, it doesn't always work, so the safest bet is to always cast explicitly, i.e.:

```sql
details = cast(:details as jsonb)
```

#### The `NULL` value

You're not setting the timestamp to `NULL` (the value), you're setting it to `'NULL'` (the string literal). Just omit the apostrophes

```sql
created_timestamp = NULL
```

#### Using the code generator and the DSL

You probably have your reasons for using plain SQL like this, but please note that jOOQ's API, DSL, and code generator handle all of these things for you transparently. You'd just write:

```java
ctx.update(CUSTOMER)
   .set(CUSTOMER.NAME, name)

   // You could even attach a Converter to this column to auto-convert
   // between your object representation and the JSONB representation!
   .set(CUSTOMER.DETAILS, jsonb(objectmapper.writeValueAsString(object)))
   .setNull(CUSTOMER.CREATED_TIMESTAMP)
   .returning()
   .fetchMaps();
```

See this blog post on [why it is usually recommended to use code generation with jOOQ](https://blog.jooq.org/why-you-should-use-jooq-with-code-generation/).

Comment: i tried this one `created_timestamp = NULL` but it still gives me same syntax error

Comment: @RyuzakiL: Well, what is the exact error?

Comment: actually it's same error and it just change the field name `created_timestamp` syntax error at line 65